# ExifInterface orientation is always 0 in Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm working on Xamarin.Forms application where I want to implement take picture functionality.

I have implemented this functionality and its working. But just now I have encountered one issue on Samsung device. So when I take photo from device then it is getting rotated automatically. But same behaviour works perfectly on other devices like Moto X.

To resolve this I'm checking the ExifInterface of that image but somehow its always 0.

For taking photo, my code snippet is as below:

```
            var image = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync (new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions {
            Directory = "../Library",
            Name = ImageFilename
        });
```

And then for getting the orientation,

```
var exifInterface = new ExifInterface (image.Path);
        int orientation = exifInterface.GetAttributeInt (ExifInterface.TagOrientation, 0);
```

But if I check the orientation, then it is always 0.

I have also passed -1 in exifInterface.GetAttributeInt but it also gives 0.

Does anyone encountered such issue? Or I'm doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

What version of `CrossMedia` are you using? There is a fix for a similar issue in [2.4.0-beta1](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/issues/134)

Also what device are you using? Some devices are naturally landscape (Such as the Samsung Galaxy Tab S4) which can cause issues with orientation and the current rotation of the image.

Comment: Current version I have is 2.3.0. And latest version is still in beta phase so I'm not sure I will be able to use it because of some policies. And I'm facing this issue only on Samsun device, right now I'm testing on Note 5 and Galaxy S5.